# Ubuntu 18.04: Citrix Receiver 13.10 always in Fullscreen mode

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, fullscreen, citrix, icaclient

UPDATE 5-aug 2018:
On my Desktop workstation I have created 2 VM's (using Virtual Machine Manager).
1) Ubuntu 16.04: clean installation + clean installation of Citrix Reveicer 13.10. I didn't have any problems with the installation of Ctrix Receiver.
The display resolution on the VM is set to 1400 * 1050.
On the VM I have set the preferred window size, of the Citrix session, to 1340 * 970.

When I connect to a Citrix server from FireFox, the Citrix session will fit nicely in a window on the VM without any problems

2) Ubuntu 18.04.1:  clean installation + clean installation of Citrix Reveicer 13.10. I didn't have any problems with the installation of Ctrix Receiver.
The display resolution on the VM is set to 1400 * 1050.
On the VM I have set the preferred window size, of the Citrix session, to 1340 * 970.

When I connect to a Citrix server from FireFox, strangely enough the Citrix session stretches to the screen size of the VM. This doesn't happen on the Ubuntu 16.04 VM, only on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

When I set the preferred Citrix window size to 1280 * 840, and connect again to the Citrix server, the Citrix session will fit nicely in a window on the VM without any problems
After setting the preferred Citrix window size to 1280 * 860 or 1340 * 840 or 1300 * 840, strangely enough the Citrix session stretches to the screen size of the VM.

Still any help is appreciated, I use Ubuntu and Citrix Receiver very often
Many thanks, Ronald

/*--=====================================================================--*/
I recently did clean/fresh installation Ubuntu 18.04 and Citrix Receiver 13.10. I was able to connect to a Citrix server from FireFox.

But each time the session appeared in Fullscreen mode.
Using the Citrix configmgr tool, resulted in error-message about missing libcurl.so.4
I managed to solve this error-message with this command

> sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev

After this the configmgr worked correctly and I was able to change from Fullscreen mode to Window mode, then saved and closed the configmgr.

From FireFox connected again to Citric server, but still in Fullscreen mode.
I have changed also

> Home/.ICAclient/All_Regions.ini

and set the option lines

> DesiredHRES=1800
>   DesiredVRES=1124

Same option lines changed in the file

> Home/.ICAClient/wfclient.ini

But every time I connect to Citrix Server, the session is still in Fullscreen mode.

On my previous Ubuntu 16.04 and Citrix Reveiver 13.2, I didn't have this problem.

I have also downgraded Citrix Receiver to 13.3 on the 18.04 installation, but no change.

My question:
is there anyone how has the same type of problem
And is there any solution or reference, in how to fix the problem?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks,
Ronald

Comment: All I can say for me is: The values in `wfclient.ini` seem to have been ignored, while setting the values in `All_Regions.ini` had the desired effect.